# Plotting and displaying a complex network with a react native component?

Tags: react-native, graph, graph-algorithm, graphviz

I have a rather large [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28discrete_mathematics%29?wprov=sfla1) consisting of about 50 nodes and 100 vertices represented in [DOT graph notation language](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) which I want to display on a mobile device using React Native. Ideally, I would like to be able to fine-tune the layouting algorithm, e.g. the parameters of the Fruchterman–Reingold algorithm for [force-directed graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing?wprov=sfla1).

So far, I figured out two approaches:

1. Convert my input data such that it can be digested by [react-graph-vis](https://github.com/crubier/react-graph-vis#readme) and plot my network on the fly. For adjusting the parameters of the drawing algorithm, things might get tricky.
2. Generate a SVG graphics on the server using [graphviz](http://graphviz.org) and on the mobile device just display the SVG so that you can zoom and scroll. For this I found [react-native-svg-pan-zoom](https://github.com/garblovians/react-native-svg-pan-zoom) whose last commit is 2 years ago (as of Dec 2019). This approach has the disadvantage that it does not work offline.

Which other alternatives do I have? Did I miss some out-of-the-box solution? Any help is appreciated!